# Quotations in background styling?

Tags: html, css

Say I want to add a background image to something, I might write:

```
background: url(/images/button_bg.png) repeat-x scroll left bottom #146BAE
```

However, if I look at this code in Firebug, it will display the following:

```
background: url("/images/button_bg.png") repeat-x scroll left bottom #146BAE
```

Are the quotation marks around the image path significant in any way? Do they make it faster/more standards compliant, or does Firebug just do this to make the code a little easier to read?

I've also seen single quotes ( '  ' ) used too, I'm not sure if they're any different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are significant if the path to that image contains non-alphanumeric characters or spaces.

It's best to wrap the url with `"` (quotes) or `'` (single quote). It isn't a standard.

Comment: Ah ok, hadn't taken weird characters into consideration, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They are significant if you have special characters in the URI,( [see the spec here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)) otherwise they are optional

Answer (score 1):

We (web.de) don't use quotation marks around background Image Paths, they don't make the parser Faster.

Answer (score 0):

we should use quotes for URI Values

```
(Uniform Resource Identifiers which includes URLs, URNs, etc)
```

The format of a URI value is 'url' and its an optional single quote (') or double quote (")
We can use any of one but the two quote characters must be the same whatever we are using give below the live demo as well as.

for example :-

body { background: url("http://www.example.com/pinkish.png") } [`double quote (") demo`](http://tinkerbin.com/hXDrVhzd)

body { background: url('http://www.example.com/pinkish.png') }  [`single quote (') demo`](http://tinkerbin.com/4S9Stbnh)